# UrlManager hide id - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

this is my urlManager in config/web.php

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
            '' => 'site/index',
            '/<naslovcic:.*?>' => 'site/blog-post',
            '<alias:kundennutzen|berater|garantie|leistungen|impressum|referenzen|blog|kontakt>' => 'site/<alias>',
        ]
    ],
```

Is there any possible way that I can hide id from my url?
So for example, now it is http://localhost/17/my-new-blog-post
And I want it like this http://localhost/my-new-blog-post